# How do I create a fade in effect from one image to another on UIImageView?

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview, uiviewanimationtransition

Hello I have the following code in attempt to fade in images in and out for my imageview:

```
- (void)oneFingerSwipeLeft:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
// Insert your own code to handle swipe left
[imageview setAlpha:0];
[UIImageView beginAnimations:NULL context:nil];
[UIImageView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
[UIImageView setAnimationDuration:1];
[imageview setAlpha:1];
[UIImageView commitAnimations];
imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.jpg"];
}

- (void)oneFingerSwipeRight:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
// Insert your own code to handle swipe right
[imageview setAlpha:0];
[UIImageView beginAnimations:NULL context:nil];
[UIImageView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
[UIImageView setAnimationDuration:1];
[imageview setAlpha:1];
[UIImageView commitAnimations];
imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.jpg"];
```

However what this does is kind of flash the image in a way, how do I make a smooth fade in/out transition from one image to another?

Also I I have images called image1,image2, image3, etc.
How would I go about making transitions from image 1 to 2 to 3 every time I swipe?

Answer (score 3):

To start with, don't use 'old style' animations. From the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/beginAnimations%3acontext%3a):

> Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. You should use
>   the block-based animation methods to specify your animations instead.

To fade between 2 imageViews try something like this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView * myImageView;

- (void) fadeToImage: (UIImage *) newImage
{
    // First create a new imageView in the same place as the current one
    UIImageView * newImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: self.myImageView.frame];
    newImageView.image = newImage;
    newImageView.alpha = 0.0;
    [self.myImageView.superview insertSubview: newImageView aboveSubview: self.myImageView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration: 1.0
                     animations:^{

                         // Cross-fade the images
                         newImageView.alpha = 1.0;
                         self.myImageView.alpha = 0.0;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         // Finally remove the old imageView and replace with the new
                         [self.imageView removeFromSuperview];
                         self.myImageView = newImageView;
                     }];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Doing a proper cross dissolve is a little more work, but not much.  To start, you need three views, a parent view and two child views.  The parent view can be a generic `UIView` (in the code below, I'm using the view controller's main view as the parent view). The two children are `UIImageView`s, and are subviews of the parent view. The children should have identical `frame`s, but the children don't have to be the same size as the parent.

Initially, the `currentImageView` should have its `hidden` property set to `NO`, and the `nextImageView` should have its `hidden` property set to `YES`. The transition code looks like this.

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                  duration:1.0
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                    self.nextImageView.hidden = NO;
                    self.currentImageView.hidden = YES;
                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    UIImageView *temp = self.currentImageView;
                    self.currentImageView = self.nextImageView;
                    self.nextImageView = temp;
                }
];
```

The pointer swap in the `completion` block allows you to do the next transition simply by changing the `image` property of `self.nextImageView` and then run the transition again.